# Custom Report Needed. Click detail at Subscriber level

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, custom-report-type

I need to a create a report that shows me by date at Subscriber level what links have been clicked in emails.

I can see that it's possible to produce reports to show click activity, but this isn't at Subscriber level.

I can also see that it's possible to produce a Subscriber level report that shows the *number* of clicks for a Subscriber, but not *what* they've clicked on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an SQL query and get this data from the [_Click Data View](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5).

Create a Data Extension first with the required fields, and then [automate the query](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm) to run daily or weekly, per your requirements.

Here's an example query:

```
SELECT EventDate, SubscriberKey, URL, LinkName
FROM _Click
```

You can also run this ad hoc in [Query Studio](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/05/query-studio-for-marketing-cloud/).

---

Here are the fields available in the _Click Data View. Follow this link to get all the details such as data types, etc: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5

```
SubscriberID
SubscriberKey
AccountID
OYBAccountID
JobID
ListID
BatchID
EventDate
Domain
TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
URL
TriggeredSendCustomerKey
LinkName
LinkContent
IsUnique
```

You can also download a visual representation of all Data Views [here](https://sfmarketingcloudhome.files.wordpress.com/2019/08/dataviews_sfmarketing.cloud_ver1.pdf).

Comment: Quick draw @Zuzannamj strikes again!

Comment: @zuzannamj - please leave some questions for the rest of us!

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Comment: all right @LukasLunow ;-)

Comment: One more question actually.  Do Salesforce have anywhere a dictionary of all of the column headers one can use in an email performance report?  URL, LinkName etc.

I can't find one anywhere

Comment: It's here in a table: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5 but I'll paste it into the answer for your convenience as well.

Comment: Perfect, thanks